# Оптимизированный вариант SQL запроса

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Добрый ночи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть. Есть у меня данные:

```
Данные1
Данные2
....
Данные32
```

Все эти данные уникальны, то есть например Данные1 - это стоимость, а Данные2 - это имя и.т.д. Скажите, как лучше всего сохранять все эти данные (а их может быть порядка 1000) в базу данных. В одну таблицу, создав для каждого пункта по своей колонке? Или же все таки лучше сделать таблицу с колонками

```
id,name,value
```

Где `id`, это номер данных,  `name` - это имя пункта (например Данные1, или Данные2) а `value`, это его значение.  И туда уже записывать эти данные и извлекать их по айдишнику.

Comment: Вариантов много, выбор зависит от предполагаемого использования. Напр. надо ли будет искать товары, где цена от M до N? Или где likes>50? Уточните, как будут данные использоваться.

Comment: *bad* , так плохо делать.

Answer (score 3):

Интернет-магазин — значит рано или поздно вам захочется и аналитику считать, и рекомендации делать. Поэтому стоит хранить данные в оптимальном, индексируемом и доступном виде.

Надо завести все 32 колонки или больше. Тип поля `Text` годится для неограниченно длинных кусков текста, напр. содержания поста в блоге. В вашем случае, наверное, только поле `desc` (описание) будет `Text`. Но по нему медленно искать. Для коротких строк лучше ставьте тип поля `VARCHAR(максимальная предполагаемая длина поля в байтах)`, и создайте индекс по каждому полю, если оно участвует в условиях `WHERE ДанныеN = 'xxx'` или JOIN'ах - это заметно ускорит поиск и выборку.

Альтернативный вариант, когда не известно точно, какие именно будут поля, и скорость не супер-важна — писать необязательные параметры в одно длинное поле. Как [JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), или ещё проще, через некий разделитель, который в названиях и значениях полей точно никогда не встретится. В отдельные колонки можно вынести только id и несколько обязательных параметров, по которым возможен поиск. Остальные атрибуты получать уже в коде, развернув текстовую строку в ассоциативный массив или объект со свойствами. Пример записи с JSON:

```
id    name    category    attributes
1234  MacBook ноутбуки    {"model":"MacBook Pro 2012", "year":2012, "likes":15}
```

Comment: JSON не соответствует условию 1НФ, лучше такого не предлагать :)

Comment: «Вы, верно, никогда не бывали в Сингапуре!» (Пираты Карибского Моря-1) Второй вариант ближе к [NoSQL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Answer (score 3):

То что вы описали - это паттерн [Entity Attribute Value (EAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

На Хабре есть [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/45935/) с одним из вариантов реализации EAV на PHP и MySQL.

Comment: данный вариант оптимален для интернет-магазина, когда фактически структурой базы будут управлять (добавлять/менять свйоства, включать/исключать из фильтра) люди слабо представляющие что такое (СУ)БД.  

Следует выделить подчиненные сущности и разделить их месторасположение:

* Цены в разрезе характеристик (цвета, размеры) в отдельной таблице
* Остатки аналогично ценам
* Дополнительные свойства товаров, не влияющие на цену, но участвующие в пользовательском фильтре, в одной или нескольких таблицах (разделенным по типам).

Comment: Да, согласен, EAV более ресурсоемкий подход по сравнению с обычной реализацией структуры БД. Получается дополнительный уровень абстракции. База в базе.

Я в своих проектах для управления кастомными свойствами делал обертку над `ALTER TABLE`. Для каждой сущности отдельная таблица с набором кастомных полей.

Но, тем не менее, целый паттерн придумали! Значит имеет право на существование :))

Answer (score 2):

Слишком абстрактно вы про свои данные говорите, проектирование структуры БД зависит как раз таки от семантики ваших данных, вряд ли кто то конкретно сможет ответить на ваш вопрос, взглянув только на Данные[i] i = 1..32

Comment: Ну допустим это интернет магазин. И имеются вот такие данные
id name price size count lang weight likes desc data status

И допустим в интернет магазине, порядка 1000 товаров. В этой таблице name и desc, единственные данные, кто могут иметь больше чем 10 символов. id - это первичный авто инкрементный ключ. Поля price,size,lang,weight,data,name,desc - будут иметь тип TEXT, а status, count, likes - будут иметь без знаковое целое число. Примерно так. Колонок будет больше, но они в оснавном будут обычными целыми числами или не большими строками.

Comment: lang - в отдельный справочник;
price - лучше держать во float;
не понятно что такое data);
разбивайте описание вашего товара все таки по таблицам ;
status наверное то что есть ли он на складе или нет ;

id, name, priceByOne, count, status  - Товар ;
(Тут нужно использовать бизнес-логику, если товара нет на складе то количество = 0)
size, lang_id, weight, desc - описание товара ;
likes и прочие характеристики уже надо в таблицу статистики по товару ;
Это в общем на вскидку за пять минут.

Comment: А разве если я из таблицы точно указываю какие колонки мне нужно извлечь, то это не будет что все равно 2 таблицы? Например нужно для списка товаров, только имя и цена, то их из таблицы и буду вызывать. data - это моя опечатка, я хотел сказать date.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про нормализацию БД, потом подумайте, как организовать вашу базу. Возможно, данные можно представить в виде нескольких таблиц.

Comment: Почитайте про нереляционные модели данных, про NoSQL, и подумайте, как, например, организован Амазон с их немалым количеством товаров самого разного свойства.

Comment: Хотя, тут вопрос про MySQL. В котором тоже можно организовать schema-free хранилище! : )